# SQL Pivot Total Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am building an NFL Pickem application.  The query in question should show a list of all players in the league along with the team they picked to win each game in a given week.  This sample is hard coded for week 1 to keep it simpler and focus on my main question.

I am getting stuck trying to add an additional column for Total Points.  This Total Points column should perform a calculation based on the Pick.ConfidencePoints column for each player for the given week.

The query below is working the way I want except for the Total Points column. 
 Whenever I try to add that column things get messed up.

The query currently produces results that look like this:

[image]

### Here is the current query:

```
SELECT Player, [1],[2],[3]
FROM    

    (SELECT
        Player.Name AS Player,
        Game.Week,
        Team.CityShort,
        Game.ID AS GameId
    FROM Pick
    LEFT JOIN Player ON Pick.PlayerId = Player.Id
    LEFT JOIN Team ON Pick.PickedWinnerTeamId = Team.Id
    LEFT JOIN Game ON Pick.GameId = Game.Id
    WHERE Game.Week = 1
    GROUP BY Player.Name, Game.Week, Team.CityShort, Game.Id) AS SourceData


PIVOT
(
MAX (CityShort)
FOR GameId IN ([1],[2],[3])
) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are used?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: The Game.Week condition in the WHERE clause turns that LEFT JOIN result into regular inner join result. Move condition to ON clause to get true left join result.

Comment: following are missing from your question; 1. the table structure with sample data of tables you joined in your query.  2. "Score" column you want to total. 3.Expected result set

Comment: @jarlh MS SQL Server.

Comment: @jarlh My apologies for including the GROUP BY.  I must have left that in the query from some of my previous attempts at solving the problem myself.  It can be removed.

Comment: @ARr0w What is the preferred method of sharing the table structure?  (Sorry for being a newb).

Comment: All the multiple tables you are using in join with sample data in each and your expected result. Table(s) and sample data script will be a up vote for you in future with proof of your effort. Sharing query effort you did related to your question like in this question you hust shared your effort, not the whole test environment for others along with it for them to help you out.

Comment: [Here] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c2KzvV76YB0bkLZRpt5e47Ui0Y4R2-kq) is a link to my script file with all tables and sample data.<br/><br/>My expected result would be as mentioned in original post, I would like to take the current query that I posted (minus the GROUP BY) and then add a column that is a calculation of the total points for correct picks minus the total points for incorrect picks for each player for the given week.<br/><br/>The correct pick is determined by the comparing the Pick.PickedWinnerTeamId with the Game.WinningTeamId.

Comment: If the Game.WinningTeamId is null or 33 (a blank value I added for drop down menus) it should not count as correct or incorrect.

Comment: [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q53e0gaScsEBhQpOb1Nr9Vxnsclv76vg) is another similar query for reference.  In this query I figured out how to get the total I wanted but it is a simpler query in that it only shows Player name and season total points without the complexities of a pivot or filter by week.